# How to pass parameter to map function during calling mapreduce function?

Tags: matlab, hadoop, mapreduce

I'have a mapreduce function whose output should be fed to another mapreduce function
the code is as follows

```
function clustering = parallel_clustering_kmeans(data)
%% find first clustering from all chunks
result = mapreduce(data,@k_means_Mapper,@k_means_Reducer);
result = readall(result);
index = result{:,1};
index = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,strrep(index,',',' '),'un',0));
clustering = mapreduce(data,@k_means_Mapper_second,@k_means_Reducer);
end
```

The first function works well
    result = mapreduce(data,@k_means_Mapper,@k_means_Reducer);
however, I want to pass the index as a parameter for the k_means_Mapper_second

The code must be as follows

```
function k_means_Mapper_second(data,index,intermidiateValuesOut)
distance = zeros(size(data,1),size(index,1));
parfor i = 1:size(data,1)
    for j = 1:size(index,1)
        distance(i,j) =  sum((data(i,:)-index(j,:)).^2).^0.5;
    end
end
for i = 1:size(distance,1)
    x = distance(i,:);
    [~,ind] = min(x);
    key = combine_values(data(i,:));
    addmulti(intermidiateValuesOut,key,ind);
end
end
```

My question is how can i pass the index as a parameter to the k_means_Mapper_second function in the last line

```
clustering = mapreduce(data,@k_means_Mapper_second,@k_means_Reducer);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [anonymous function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your function within an anonymous function that accepts all inputs given to it by `mapreduce` but then calls your function, passing only the relevant values. For your case it would look something like:

```
mapperFunc = @(data, info, interim)k_means_Mapper_second(data, index, interim);
clustering = mapreduce(data, mapperFunc, @k_means_Reducer);
```